# get id of a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to this wordpress, I have created a CPT which will let me add services and these services are nested by categories, so I would like to present the services of each category, according to the category that is entered.

I hope you can help me, thanks

Upgrade:
I have created a PT with the following code

function create_servicios_cpt() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Servicios', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Servicios', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'archives' => __( 'Archivos Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'attributes' => __( 'Atributos Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Padres Servicios:', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Añadir nueva Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Añadir nuevo', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'Nueva Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Editar Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'Ver Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_items' => __( 'Ver Custom Posts', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Buscar Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No se encontraron Custom Posts.', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Ningún Servicios encontrado en la papelera.', 'textdomain' ),
    'featured_image' => __( 'Imagen destacada', 'textdomain' ),
    'set_featured_image' => __( 'Establecer imagen destacada', 'textdomain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Borrar imagen destacada', 'textdomain' ),
    'use_featured_image' => __( 'Usar como imagen destacada', 'textdomain' ),
    'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insertar en la Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Subido a esta Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list' => __( 'Lista de Custom Posts', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navegación por el listado de Custom Posts', 'textdomain' ),
    'filter_items_list' => __( 'Lista de Custom Posts filtradas', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label' => __( 'Servicios', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
    'taxonomies' => array('Categoria', ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'servicios', $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_servicios_cpt', 0 );

And Taxonomies with:

/ Taxonomy Key: categoria
function create_categoria_tax() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Categorias', 'taxonomy general name', 'dolce' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Categoria', 'taxonomy singular name', 'dolce' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categorias', 'dolce' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categorias', 'dolce' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Categoria', 'dolce' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Categoria:', 'dolce' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Categoria', 'dolce' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Categoria', 'dolce' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Categoria', 'dolce' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Categoria Name', 'dolce' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Categorias', 'dolce' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => __( '', 'dolce' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'servicios'),
);
register_taxonomy( 'categoria', array('servicios', ), $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_categoria_tax' );

Then, when creating new "services", the normal ones, as well as the categories, my problem is to show the categories with each service of each of them.

In my logic I would call a template and in this I would verify the id of the category that is being called and with the loop I would call all the services of this category, but I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: really great,we wish you good luck!

Comment: You should consider sharing your code or ask a question, so we can help you. Do you load data from database or do you use wordpress functions? If second, have you tried `the_category_ID()`?

Comment: I have updated with the code, and I have been more explicit to be able to arrive, I hope you can understand what I need

Answer (score 1):

- Category default use for Post. So if you create new CTP Services --> You need create taxonomy ( same same category but use for CTP https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies ) or use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/.
- Now you want get taxonomy use get term ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term )

Hope it will help you